# lost cassandra authentication user after adding a new node

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

When ı add a new node to my cassandra cluster, ı lost my authentication user.

update seeds and restart nodes it turns default user -u cassandra -p cassandra

ı lost my user which ı have already created before

Comment: Also, consider the fact that `cassandra` user is authenticated with `QUORUM` consistency level, and if you lost some nodes, then you may not able to login. See instructions there on how correctly create another super user instead of `cassandra`: https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/security/Auth/secCreateRootAccount.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have seen this happen before.  What happens, is that the new node forces a token range re-calculation.  If your new node is also a *seed* node, this complicates matters as seed nodes *do not* bootstrap data, and must be populated via repair/rebuild.  Essentially, your pre-existing user is probably still there, but the node primarily responsible for its token in the `system_auth.roles` table has changed, but data movement has not occured.

First, double-check the replication strategy used on the `system_auth` keyspace.  By default, it is set to `{'class':'SimpleStrategy','replication_factor':'1'}` which is not sufficient (IMO) for anything other than local development.  I always recommend changing this to the `NetworkTopologyStrategy`, and then specify replication by data center.

With that complete, run a repair on each node:

`nodetool repair system_auth -full`

That should bring back your previous user.

Note: Instead of a full repair, you might be able to get away with querying each table in `system_auth` at consistency `ALL` (which forces a read repair):

```
dba@cqlsh> use system_auth;
dba@cqlsh:system_auth> consistency ALL;
Consistency level set to ALL.
dba@cqlsh:system_auth> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM roles;
dba@cqlsh:system_auth> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM role_permissions;
dba@cqlsh:system_auth> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM role_members;
dba@cqlsh:system_auth> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM resource_role_permissons_index;
```

With either the full repair or read repair complete, your previous user should work again.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I got why this happen. Take my notes. Also ı have one more issu about adding a new datacenter to existing cluster. Do you have any comment for this issue. stackoverflow issue id: 55509650